# Use variable as @media query

Tags: sass

I come from using `less` with code that looked like this

```
@myvar: ~"(max-width: @{max})";
```

and using it like so

```
@media @myvar {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

But after changing to sass it will not compile, it says `; expected`
This is the new sass code

```
$myvar: #{"(max-width: ${max})"};

@media $myvar {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

How can I use my variable as a `@media` selector?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I never tested it out if i can use variables in @media but i think it should looks like

`$myBreakPoint1 = 991px; @media(max-width: $myBreakPoint1) { }`

Or u can set up variable as string with wrapp it into '' or only number to variable and write px next to it like $myBreakPoint1 px